# Comboboxcolumn in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I am starter on windows forms, and have added column of type combobox to datagridview.the gridview is not bound to any sources.

This is the error that I see when I try to click combobox

Any clues here?[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some searches, this was solved using 
mainFormThread.SetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA)

As I was initiating another thread. mainFormThread, it had to be set to STA mode.

In other cases where threads arent involved, [STATTHREAD] Attribute on main entry point should work.